# How to add reference to System.Web.Optimization for MVC 5

Tags: nuget

App_Start\BundleConfig.cs :
The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Global.asax.cs :
The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

App_Start\BundleConfig.cs : 
The type or namespace name 'BundleCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm getting the above errors when attempting to build solution.

I tried this in the Package manager Console:
(Still Build error exists)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebGrease (≥ 1.5.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Antlr (≥ 3.4.1.9004)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.4)'.
'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3' already installed.
AdminHelpDesk already has a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3'.
```

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately bundles are [no longer available in MVC5](http://www.jeffreyfritz.com/2015/05/where-did-my-asp-net-bundles-go-in-asp-net-5/)

Comment: bundles are available!!